# Best practices when defining JavaScript variables

Tags: javascript, dojo

When setting up a dojo application, what is the recommended best practice for initiating variables in reference to dom objects? I've found that I usually need reference to the parent and children objects on top of the widget itself and have been creating global placeholders with the following code.

```
var formItems = ["Item_1", "Item_2", "Item_3", ... "Item_15"];

formItems.forEach(function(formItem) {
    var items = ["frm", "dom", "dijit"];
    items.forEach(function(item) {
        var x = item + formItem;
        window[x] = undefined;
    });
});
```

vs

```
var frmItem_1, frmItem_2, frmItem_3, ... frmItem_15;
var domItem_1, domItem_2, domItem_3, ... domItem_15;
var dijitItem_1, dijitItem_2, dijitItem_3, ... dijitItem_15;
```

The variables are actually populated later in the dojo application after everything has been parsed but at "save", JSHint becomes upset due to no actual explicit variables being defined.

Comment: can you put them all in an object so that you can iterate them and only make one global?

Comment: Are you dealing primarily with dijits, where you could use the dijit registry to get handles to specific widgets, and get to specific nodes that way?

Comment: dan, probably.  Sounds like the best advice is to keep everything in 1 spot, as per pswg's advice below.

Comment: Jason, not necessarily.  That just happened to be the example I used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really like either of those options. I prefer to have as few global variables as absolutely necessary. I'd recommend initializing an array to store your items, then referencing that array in your dojo application.

```
var formItems = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
   formItems.push({
       frm: null,
       dom: null,
       dijit: null
   });
}
```

And in your dojo application replace:

- `frmItem_N` with `formItems[N].frm`
- `domItem_N` with `formItems[N].dom`
- `dijitItem_N` with `formItems[N].dijit`

You might also be able to avoid pre-populating the array if you can make your dojo application push items into the array as necessary. There may be more work you can do make the `formItems` array non-global, but it's hard to tell just from the code provided.

Comment: The numerical numbering of the vars are just placeholders for the actual variable names (E.g. Scale_X, Scale_Y, Project_Manager).  The issue is I have a lot of custom dojo modules that are loaded in via AMD and handling the event triggers in the global space is easier than trying to pass around local variables through-out the code based on the custom module call.  

The need for "frm" vs "dom" vs "dijit" are to handle visibility and functionality within the UI on the client-end depending on permissions and other properties chosen by the end user.

Comment: @disuse The same suggestion would apply, just change `formItems` from an array to an object and use property names as keys. e.g. `formItems['Scale_X'].frm` or `formItems.Scale_X.frm`

Answer (score 1):

It's all subjective and depends on your project. You can configure JSHint to make you happy.

If you wanted to satisfy the errors without changing any JSHint configs, initialize variables outside the loop, then define them inside.

```
var formItems = ["Item_1", "Item_2", "Item_3", ... "Item_15"],
    items,
    x;

formItems.forEach(function(formItem) {
    items = ["frm", "dom", "dijit"];
    items.forEach(function(item) {
       x = item + formItem;
       window[x] = undefined;
    });
});
```

Comment: I think what JSHint is probably complaining about is references to the dynamically generated variables (e.g. `frmItem_1`) in the rest of the code. This wouldn't address that issue.

Comment: Correct RE: dynamic variables.

Adding the following addressed the JSHint complaints but I plan to take the advice to make 1 global var and access it via property names as keys.

    `/* globals require: false */`
    `/* jshint unused: true, undef: false */`